# Contentfile in nuget gets compiled causing build errors

Tags: json, nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-2019

I have a nuget that has a contentfile in it. It is a `json file` and denoted in the nuspec file when the `nuget` is packed.

When installing the `nuget` in a regular wpf app, I get a couple build errors. It appears that `Visual Studio` is trying to compile the `.json file`. Wondering if anyone knows what may cause this. As you'll see in the nuspec snippet I have `BuildAction=None` in the nuspec

> ContentFile.json(1,1,1,2): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
>
> ContentFile.json(4,16,4,26): error CS1001: Identifier expected
>
> ContentFile.json(4,37,4,45): error CS1001: Identifier expected

[image]

Comment: To achieve this, you should add `<file src="**\Resources\ContentFile.json" (the reative path of the file in the current project folder) target="ContentFiles/any/any" />` under the `<file>` node. Besides,`files include="xxxxx"` under the `<contentfiles>` node is the path which is relative to the contentFiles folder inside the nuget package. So in this point, it should be  `<files include="any/any/ContentFiles.json" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" flatten="false" />`

Comment: Then after you pack this project and then install it on another project , do not forget to [clean the nuget cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders).

Comment: Hi, any uopdate for this issue? Please follow my guidance to troubleshoot your issue and if it does help you, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If your issue still persists, please feel free to let us know. It is just a reminder.

Answer (score 0):

> When installing the nuget in a regular wpf app, I get a couple build
>   errors. It appears that Visual Studio is trying to compile the .json
>   file. Wondering if anyone knows what may cause this. As you'll see in
>   the nuspec snippet I have BuildAction=None in the nuspec

I think the main point is that you mistakenly assume that `<files include="path">` is the path of the source file `ContentFile.json` in your current nuget project, which is actually the path relative to the **contentFiles** folder inside the nuget package(`xxxx.nupkg`).(You can view the **contentFiles** folder by decompressing the xxx.nupkg file).

Besides, you can check [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#using-the-contentfiles-element-for-content-files) for more detailed info.

As a right guidance, you can try this step:

**Solution**

change to these in `xxx.nuspec` file

```
....
<metadata>
....
<contentFiles>
<files include="any/any/ContentFile.json"(the relativepath of the file under the ContentFiles folder in the xxx.nupkg) buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" flatten="false" />
</contentFiles>
</metadata>

<files>
<file src="xxxxx/Resource/ContentFile.json(the relativePath of the file under the nuget project)" target="contentFiles/any/any" />
</files>
....
```

**Before** you install this package into another project , do not forget to [clean the nuget cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders).

**In additon**, you can check [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/9718) for more info.

Hope it could help you.